# How access images with dompdf and htaccess

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, dompdf

I have a server with htaccess and want to use dompdf. But no Picture is shown in my pdf which is on my server. If the Pciture is on an extern Server, the picture is visible.

Is there a solution?

Comment: I do not understand what is required here ...

Comment: Post up your code including the .htaccess files contents

Comment: Problem could be in the way you reference your images. Have you tried accessing local images similar to how you access remote ones (i.e. a URL with domain)?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many things causing this issue, but I have two potential options for the time being:

- Perhaps your .htaccess is blocking access to the images on your server.
- Maybe your server is not able to see its self (domain name not propagated yet). Try adding a line in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).